# How to execute the Windows 'printto' verb using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, printing

In the past I have used the 'printto' verb to print PDFs from with a .Net application. It looked something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(file);
psi.Verb = "printto";   // print to given printer
psi.Arguments = "LPT1";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.ErrorDialog = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

How can I do this from a Java application? Or is there an alternative approach? Note that the target platform will always be Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
public void print() {
    //The desktop api can help calling native applications in windows
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try {
        desktop.print(new File("yourFile.pdf"));
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please Note : This is the easy fix. You can also use `java's Print API` to achieve the same thing

Comment: thanks! That works but opens AcrobatReader and - even worse - leaves it open. Any ideas how to make this run in 'silent' mode?

Comment: you will have to use the print API of java to make a silent print !

Comment: Please go through the code here http://www.java-forum.org/allgemeine-java-themen/99423-pdf-itext-drucken.html